# Problem with FBA(Form based) Loging into a sharepoint site in ie 8 (64bit)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am new in Sharepoint technology. I have created a demo site. It's working fine in firefox but for some reason, I can't even login in IE browser.
Please help.
Thanks,
Saurabh

Answer (score 0):

Their is as such no problem with FBA as you have mentioned please check your internet browser settings like cookies are enabled and as well as scripting is enabled

Comment: everything was fine.but later i found the issue. problem was there because of computer name it contain the letter '_' underscore